# I cannot set my system back to English from Chinese Language

Tags: language-support, locale

I once turned my system to Chinese, now I cannot set it back to English.
I tried to change the order in Language Settings, but it doesn't work.

[image]

Chinese is always at the top. Even if I delete the language package of Chinese, it still remains. The menu of the system will return english, but all the softwares as well as the top bar remains in  Chinese.

I also tried to reset `/etc/default/locale` and `/etc/environment` but it doesn't work.

```
root@ks356457:~# cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
LANGUAGE="en_US:en_GB:zh_CN:de_DE:en_AU:en_CA:en_NZ:en"
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
root@ks356457:~# cat /etc/default/locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US:en_GB:zh_CN:de_DE:en_AU:en_CA:en_NZ:en"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
root@ks356457:~# echo $LANG $LANGUAGE
zh_CN.UTF-8 zh_CN:en
```

This is a remote server and I use remote desktop via X2GO so I can't set the language before I log in as a local machine, either.

How do I get English back? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, to be ensure that Chinese language packs are removed, give

```
sudo apt-get remove language-pack-gnome-nan*
sudo apt-get remove language-pack-gnome-zh*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

commands. If you reset /etc/default/locale file as described in [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale), issue

```
localedef --list-archive
```

command. If it generates an output like

```
en_US.utf8
zh_CN.utf8
zh_SG.utf8
```

this, run

```
sudo localedef --delete-from-archive zh_CN.utf8
sudo localedef --delete-from-archive zh_SG.utf8
sudo locale-gen
```

commands. After these commands you still see Chinese, write

```
cat ~/.pam_environment
```

command. If you see anything related to Chinese like

```
LANGUAGE=en_US:zh_CN:en
```

this, just delete "zh_CN" from the file by using Gedit. Then give the final command

```
sudo locale-gen
```

I hope this will help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

This seems a bit obvious, but you don't mention trying it so I'll answer anyway. Try click-dragging the the Chinese `汉语 (中国)` list entry below the English list entry.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it

Comment: I did do it, but it automatically turn back after reboot.